# Where to put 'create_function' statements in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-2.1

I'm working on a project with standard Django+SQLite bundle.
And I've come to situation where Django querySet API and even django 'raw()' are not enough for me to retrieve appropriate information from the database.

So I execute custom SQL directly to retrieve data. Also I need to define 'lower' function through 'create_function' interface cause SQLite can't perform case-insensitive sorting on unicode field (https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18).

My question is where should I put this 'create_function' statement? Is it normal to put it directly into a django view, so it would be executed every time the view is loaded, or I should put it somewere else, where it would be executed only once?

```
from django.db import connection


def lower(text):
    if text:
        return text.lower()
    else:
        return text


def my_view(request):
    ...
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        if (connection.vendor == 'sqlite'):
            connection.connection.create_function('lower', 1, lower)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM <my complicated select using lower>;')
        data = dictfetchall(cursor)
    ...
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307242/how-to-extend-sqlite-with-python-functions-in-django)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend SQLite with Python functions in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307242/how-to-extend-sqlite-with-python-functions-in-django)

Comment: @dirkgroten should I use snippet from your link in 'settings.py' file? Should I explicitly call this 'extend_sqlite' function from the answer somewhere?

Comment: No, it's a handler for the signal `connection_created`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) for how Django Signals works and especially scroll down to "Where should this code live?" to see where you put the code. Basically create a handlers.py file (or signals.py) inside your app and make sure you import it in `ready()` of apps.py